# what is the equivalent query of pctfree in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, oracle11g

what is the equivalent postgres query for the below:

```
CREATE TABLE SAKTRE  pctfree 10  tablespace CHARGE 
 PARALLEL 1 CACHE AS
 SELECT /*+ORDERED USE_NL(real)*/
        real.*
   FROM (
SELECT id FROM SAKTRE_MINI_0
) mini, SAKTRE_2 real
  WHERE  mini.id = real.charge_id
```

Comment: I guess `fillfactor` is the closest: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS

Answer (score 2):

[Oracle says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/physical_attributes_clause.html#GUID-A15063A9-3237-43D3-B0AE-D01F6E80B393):

> #### PCTFREE integer
>
> Specify a whole number representing the percentage of space in each data block of the database object reserved for future updates to rows of the object. The value of `PCTFREE` must be a value from 0 to 99. A value of 0 means that the entire block can be filled by inserts of new rows. The default value is 10. This value reserves 10% of each block for updates to existing rows and allows inserts of new rows to fill a maximum of 90% of each block.

The PostgreSQL equivalent is [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS):

> `fillfactor (integer)`
>
> The fillfactor for a table is a percentage between 10 and 100. 100 (complete packing) is the default. When a smaller fillfactor is specified, `INSERT` operations pack table pages only to the indicated percentage; the remaining space on each page is reserved for updating rows on that page. This gives `UPDATE` a chance to place the updated copy of a row on the same page as the original, which is more efficient than placing it on a different page. For a table whose entries are never updated, complete packing is the best choice, but in heavily updated tables smaller fillfactors are appropriate.

Note, however, that Oracle's and PostgreSQL's implementation of `UPDATE` differ radically, and that moreover 10 is the default value for `PCTFREE` in Oracle.

So rather than using a `fillfactor` of 90, which would be the literal translation, I suggest that you go with the default value of 100.